# Cocoapods Probleme

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

[Podfile][1]```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] The FlutterFire plugin cloud_firestore for macOS requires a macOS
deployment target of 10.12 or later.
```

Exception: Error running pod install

```
Hi, I've been stuck on this problem for a while, I'm trying to connect my flutter app with firebase but as soon as I put firestore on I have this problem. I modified the podfile file by putting the right version but nothing is done. I followed a lot of tutorials but none solved my problem. so please i need help.

I created my database on firebase, I configured it with xcode

Cocaopods version : 1.11.3

firebase_core: ^2.1.1

cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3

platform :ios, '12.0'


Podfile : 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYqSZ.png
```

Comment: run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then `flutter run`

Comment: I have to ask... Did you set your deployment target to 10.12 or later?

Comment: I did what you said john, but the problem still persists. Yes my version is 12.0

Comment: What version of Cocoapods do you have? How about Firebase? Can you include your podfile in the question plese

Comment: I Just edit Now

Comment: Please include your exact podfile in the question. links don't do us any good. Also, your deployment target is macOS and the podFile is for iOS. There's a lot of conflicting data in your question - perhaps you should take a closer look at your project and update the question with clearer information. Update it and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

Here are the tips:

1. Run Xcode --> Click Runner --> Change version in 'minimum deployments' f.e. to 11.0 or later
2. Go to Visual Studio Code --> go to 'macos' folder --> click 'podfile' --> change on the same version like in Xcode in platform :osx, '11.0'
3. Restart App and start with debugging again.

Let me know if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first line of your Podfile in your macOS folder. If it looks like this:
`platform :osx, '10.11'`
then change it to your desired `MACOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`